# Giving JButtons different functionalities based on state of program?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm building a GUI in Swing for an ATM that interacts with a bank model. As part of my assignment, I can only create 14 keys for the user to use to control the program: the 0-9 keys, OK, Clear, Close, and Cancel.

My question is this: because these buttons have different functions based on the state of the ATM (logging in, performing a transaction, etc.), how can I represent these different functions in an elegant manner?

My initial idea was to remove any ActionListeners associated with each button as the program navigates between states, and then insert ActionListeners associated with the specific state it is in. However, this seems clunky and redundant. Is there a better way to repurpose the buttons, or to read different purposes based on the state?

Comment: While I get the question this is not a valid question for SO. SO isn't a good place for design questions.

Comment: Design a model for each state, when the state changes, reassign the "correct" model to the view, this should allow the view to change the text of the buttons.  The model should then become responsible for performing the actual functionality of the button when it's clicked (the view would respond to the `ActionListener` and tell the model what the `actionCommand` was triggered)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could always rename the text part of the buttons and then parse the state of your ATM to redirect to the function you want to run.